# Data parsing from Model to Partial view error ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Application, In **EDIT** view I want to call data from the database and fill into the partial view that have sent through to the database when creates the request using same partial view . Currently my code I have written like below. But what happens is, If there is 4 records, It will generate 4 line, but there is no data there. All comes as empty.

```
 <ul id="RequItms" style="list-style-type: none">

    @if (Model != null && Model.GeneralItmsList != null)
      {
        foreach (var item in Model.GeneralItmsList)
          {
            Html.RenderAction("GeneralItmsPartialView", "AppRequests", Model.GeneralItmsList.ToList());
          }
       }
</ul>
```

Here is the view. This is the view I'm currently getting from the above code.

[image]

But this is the way it should load in that empty fields.

[image]

I have checked in the `Model.GeneralItemsList` There is shows the data, But I think when parsing it to the partial view must be the error occurs.

Here is the partial view code looks like.

```
@model Asp_PASMVC.Models.GeneralItms
@using Asp_PASMVC.Infrastructure

<li style="padding-bottom:15px">


    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("GeneralItmsList"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TempID)
        <div class="form-horizontal" id="quickForm" novalidate="novalidate">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Select Item Description
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attachment_Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attachment_Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Attachment Amount
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Rs.</span>

                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attachment_Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attachment_Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Attachment
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="file" name="ImageData@(Model.TempID.ToString())" id="ImageData@(Model.TempID.ToString())" multiple="multiple" data-id="Img@(Model.TempID.ToString())" onchange="checkImage(this)" />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attachment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img id="Img@(Model.TempID.ToString())" src="" alt="" width="100" height="100" class="ml-1" />
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Remove</button>
            </div>

        </div>



    }
</li>
```

I hope that I have explained this question properly. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Surely you should be passing `item` into the `RenderAction` call? And the view just needs to take a single "general item"?

Comment: Or remove the `foreach` loop from the parent view.

Comment: Also, what is `Html.BeginCollectionItem`?

Comment: @DavidG I tried by removing the ``foreach`` but when it does, It only generate 1 line without the data. **Html.BeginCollectionItem** it used when in the CREATE view, I have inserted a button. So when user click that button then load the partial view. It's code like this ``` ```

Comment: ```foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.GeneralItms Itms in Model.GeneralItmsList)
                                        {
                                            Html.RenderPartial("_GeneralItms", Itms);
                                        }```

Comment: Controller ```public ActionResult GeneralItmsPartialView()
    {
        GeneralItms obj = new GeneralItms();
        obj.TempID = Counter++;
        return PartialView("_GeneralItms", obj);
    }```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238799/discussion-between-user1983377-and-davidg).